# How get the :hover css style of an anchor with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, hover, anchor

How can i get the :hover in css stylesheet on the fly with jquery?

stupid example:

```
a.foo {
    color: red;
    font-size: 11px;
}

a.foo:hover {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 12px; 
}
```

how to retrieve that color and font-size before that mouse will go over the anchor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the css value from :hover with .css() - jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719421/get-the-css-value-from-hover-with-css-jquery)

Comment: @ZachSaucier yes but this question is older, so the other one is the duplicate

Comment: Sorry, [that's not correct](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252017/2065702)

Answer (score 4):

If you really need to, you can access this information throught the document.styleSheet property. An example is available here: http://jsfiddle.net/Xm2zU/1/

Please note that IE would need its own code to do this as it uses ".rules" rather than ".cssRules" etc.

Comment: Note that the code does not work if the stylesheets are located at another domain, because of the Same origin policy.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Extra selectors for jQuery](http://www.softwareunity.com/jquery/JQueryMoreSelectors/).

Also, you can use the `hover` event, depending on what you want to achieve. See: [jQuery hover and class selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275891/jquery-hover-and-class-selector).

Comment: not bad these extra selectors, but are they supported by jQuery 1.3? 

Yes i use the hover event already, but i need to make an "hover" script "general purpose", so it may be comfortable change the style directly on the css stylesheet and not passing directy styles to the function/object.

Comment: @avastreg: I haven't used them either, so I don't know if they work at all =)

Answer (score 1):

> how to retrieve that color and font-size before that mouse will go over the anchor?

No. You cannot retrieve the style declarations of a **:hover** pseudo class before hovering your mouse over that element. This is because JavaScript can only interact with the HTML using DOM. The style information (for the hovered state) is not available to the DOM unless there is a mouseover on the element and hence you cannot retrieve those values(even by simulating a hover state).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.hover()` function instead. 
http://api.jquery.com/hover/

```
$( "a.foo" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).css( 'color','red' );
  }, function() {
    $( this ).css( 'color','blue');
  }
);
```

Comment: not what i meant, I want to retrieve hover state from an element, not handling the hover