# Get the css value from :hover with .css() - jquery

Tags: jquery, css, hover

So Im setting up a menu that has different background :hover colors. The buttons backgrounds will be a grey color and upon hover the button *animate()* to its respective color.

I can grab the original default color of whatever button I hover over like this:

```
var origBackgroundColor = $(this).css('background-color');
```

But is it possible to get the color from a css :hover property that I set? I will have the :hover colors set for each button because if someone doesn't have JS enabled the navigation will still have :hover effects working.

Something like this(Or is there another way):

```
var hoverColor = $(this).css('background-color:hover');
```

Any ideas? is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that in order to get the `background-color` of the `:hover` pseudo, it will first require a browser event to apply the style. In other words, I think you could get it *when* you do a hover with the mouse, but not until then.

Could be that you could wait until the user does a hover, then grab the color, override it with the default, store it for future reference, then do your animation, but that may be more trouble that simply coordinating your JS and CSS.

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/UXzx2/

```
    // grab the default color, and create a variable to store the hovered.
var originalColor = $('div').css('background-color');
var hoverColor;

$('div').hover(function() {
      // On hover, if hoverColor hasn't yet been set, grab the color
      //    and override the pseudo color with the originalColor
    if( !hoverColor ) {
        hoverColor = $(this).css('background-color');
        $(this).css('background-color',originalColor);
    }
      // Then do your animation
    $(this).animate({backgroundColor:hoverColor});
});
```

Comment: updated with an unhover function to complete the effect http://jsfiddle.net/UXzx2/1/

Comment: Thanks @generalhenry. I was too lazy. ;o)

Comment: thats actually pretty smart because your triggering the hover without doing anything but store the value then u animate it :] nice! thanks too.

Comment: thanks for all the help well i tried the answer you gave me for my given situation. i cant seem to get it to work when there are multiple elements. i set up a simple case scenario to show you. they both either hover orange or both green, depending on which one  you start with...http://jsfiddle.net/UXzx2/5/

Comment: i feel like it is a scope issue, but i cant figure out how to remedy it

Comment: @Nils R: You have 2 different hover colors, but you're sharing the same variable. If you need to store 2 different colors, you'll need 2 different variables to reference. It gets a little confusing when you have one `:hover` affecting every `div` and the other affecting a `div` with a specific class. If you're going to have multiple, it would be better to give them unique classes in order to more easily distinguish between them. Then use 2 different variables with appropriate names to reference the different classes.

Comment: you can just make a couple arrays to track all the colors eg: http://jsfiddle.net/UXzx2/9/

Comment: I set it up with the elements i will be using in the configuration it will be in. http://jsfiddle.net/U9txA/
my problem is that sub-level elements dont .hover(). Also does this only work if jqueryUI is loaded? I mean i turned it off and it didnt work, so i guess that is a yes, but what part of that code is UI only. all the functions used are available in jQuery.

Comment: @Nils R: The part that requires jQueryUI is animating the color. You don't need the entire jQueryUI though. You can create a custom download. I'll take a look at your example.

Comment: @Nils R: The reason your sub element doesn't work is that the class name you assigned it doesn't match the class name in your stylesheet. The element has `test-color`, while the stylesheet just has `test`. Change it to `test-color` and it works.

Comment: wow i jump way to fast. i think im getting a bit frustrated thats why haha. well here is the one with the fixed class names. http://jsfiddle.net/U9txA/1/

I do notice that when you hover over the sub element the parent will hover too. ?

Comment: @patrick on my site i have the color animation plugin loading with jquery so i dont need to upload jqueryUI, but thanks i was wondering.

Comment: @Nils R: Yes, that is because when you hover a child, you're also hovering over its parent. By the way, here's a version that uses `.data()` to associate the colors with the specific element instead of using an Array. The call to `$(this).index('li')` requires a DOM selection on every event. With `.data()` each element just looks up its value stored against that specific element.

Comment: ...yes, a plugin is a good idea if you don't need the rest of jQueryUI.

Comment: Thanks, I will play around with it. this is the link, u forgot it :]
http://jsfiddle.net/U9txA/2/

Comment: @Nils R: Ha! Yes I did forget it!. Glad you found it. :o)

Answer (score 0):

```
            // How about writing anonymous function using JQuery, 
            // that encapsulate the originalColor:
            $(function() {
                var originalColor = $('div').css('background-color');
                $('div').hover(
                     function() {
                        $(this).css('background-color','cyan');
                     },
                     function () {                            
                        $(this).css('background-color', originalColor);
                    }
                );
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery works with almost every css selector,
So in this case also this should work fine.
Try the code below.

```js
$("li").hover(function(){
  var color = $(this).find(".link").css("color");
  console.log(color);
});
```

```css
a{
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

a:hover{
  color: rgb(255, 165, 0);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <li><a href="#" class="link">Sample Link</a></li>
</nav>
```

$(".targetClassName:hover").css("background-color");`