# Get hover background-color

Tags: jquery, css

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert($('.ui-btn:hover').css("background-color"));
});
```

The alert function is always undefined;

I don't want to use .hover function.

Comment: Why not use the .hover function? I don;t think there is another way. Also, you can hover it momentarily and then return it to its default state

Comment: Place debugger above your code, Your chrome/ Firebug to watch the objects

Comment: I want background color of .ui-btn:hover at dom ready

Comment: possible duplicate of [How get the :hover css style of an anchor with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654295/how-get-the-hover-css-style-of-an-anchor-with-jquery)

Comment: there isn't suitable answer for my requirement

Comment: What is your limitation to not using `.hover function`.

Comment: I've Used like.


` $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.ui-btn').trigger("mouseover");
        $('.ui-btn').hover(function () {
            $('.gbCategory').css("background-color", $(this).css("background-color"));
        })
       
    })`

Comment: have you tried mouse events like: mouseEnter and mouseover

Comment: but it's not my requirement.

Comment: @user3252143  the selector has no way of detecting `:hover` since that's a pure CSS thing. This is a known issue. but there is many way to handle this scenario to getting expected solution. will be better the add what you want.