# Problem with adding and removing classes with jQuery when hovering over a list item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a class to a list item when I hover over it, and then remove it and add it to a different list item if a different list item is hovered over.

Here's what I tried:

jQuery -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#results").text("Tournaments");
        $("#Tournaments").addClass("box-active");
        $("#box ul li").hover(function() {
            var show = $(this).attr('id');
            $("#results").text(show);
            $("#box ul li").each(function() {
                $(this).removeClass("box-active");
                });
            $("#box ul li#" + show).addClass("box-active");
            });
        });
```

HTML  -

```
    <div id="box">
        <ul>
            <li id="Tournaments">Tournaments</li>
            <li id="Join">Join</li>
            <li id="Forums">Forums</li>
            <li id="GameBattles">GameBattles</li>
            <li id="Practice">Practice</li>
        </ul>
        <p>Hovering over: <span id="results"></span></p>
    </div>
```

When I hover over an item, it changes the class, but if I hover over I different one it removes the class over the item I first hovered over, but doesn't add the class to the new item I'm hovering over. Not sure why, and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275891/jquery-hover-and-class-selector) may help.

Could be something like this:

```
   $('#box ul li').hover( function(){
      $(this).addClass('box-active');
      $("#results").text($(this).attr('id'));
   },
   function(){
      $(this).removeClass('box-active');
      $("#results").text('');
   });
```

EDIT: this will remove the class when you stop hovering over the li, not sure if that's your desired functionality or not

Answer (score 0):

For one, no reason to put multiple id tags in a search try:

```
$("li#" + show).addClass("box-active");
```

but even better, since you are in the li itself:

```
$(this).addClass('box-active');
```

I'm not sure if this will work, but try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#results").text("Tournaments");
    $("#Tournaments").addClass("box-active");
    $("#box ul li").hover(function() {
        $("#results").text( $(this).attr('id') );
        $("#box ul li.box-active").removeClass('box-active');
        $(this).addClass('box-active');
    });
});
```