# background-color change on rollover not working in IE, FF

Tags: html, css, rollover

this seems very simple and im puzzled as to why its not working...I want to change the background image of a DIV when rolling over it. It works on chrome and FF on a mac - but then not FF, IE on PC

CSS -  /media/css/mystandard.css

```
div.flipper {background-color: #FFFFFF;}
div.flipper:hover {background-color: #F8FBFE;}
```

HTML

```
<HTML> <HEAD> <link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/css/mystandard.css"/></HEAD><BODY>        
<div class="flipper" >  
hello stack overflow!               
</div>
</BODY></HTML>
```

re:Catfish

Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately I can't use the  tags because I plan on having the background color of a full DIV change (sort of like twitter.com Tweets view on rollover) and dont want to make all the text in the div a link

Comment: FYI, your HEAD element should not be inside the BODY.

Comment: aaah, you're right that was just a copy/paste typo - ill fix

Comment: it should be working on both FF and IE7+ PC so there must be a problem maybe in how you link your stylesheet ("import CSS here") - can we have the complete page or online test?

Comment: @darma see updated html code above

Comment: Which IE and Firefox version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to use a `<div>`, you'll need to use javascript to do the hover.  I suggest using jQuery for simplicity:

```
$("div.flipper").hover(
  function() { $(this).addClass("hover"); },
  function() { $(this).removeClass("hover"); }
);
```

Then change your CSS to:

```
div.flipper {background-color: #FFFFFF;}
div.hover   {background-color: #F8FBFE;}
```

Comment: where do i put the jquery function?

Comment: nevermind figured it out thanks!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275891/jquery-hover-and-class-selector

Comment: do you have a link to the page in question?

Comment: unfortunately not, its behind a firewall. i fixed the show hide issue but now there is a problem with IE where the rollover doesnt always work. see my new post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550259/hover-in-ie-not-working-when-hovering-over-full-div

Answer (score 1):

Not all browsers support the :hover pseudo attribute on anything except an anchor tag `<a>`. You'll have to change you're html to

```
<HTML><BODY> <HEAD> import CSS here </HEAD>     
<div class="flipper" >
<a href="#">  
hello stack overflow!
</a>               
</div>
</BODY></HTML>
```

and youre css to

```
div.flipper a{background-color: #FFFFFF;}
div.flipper a:hover {background-color: #F8FBFE;}
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is with your link for css. You have  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/css/mystandard.css"/>`

the first slice before media creates the problem.
Use this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="media/css/mystandard.css"/>`