# Javascript Jquery get element by class with hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to create a quiz example using **Jquery**.However I am a bit lost with how to get the css class with hover on Jquery.
**My css code is the following:**

```
.right{
  background-color: white;
}
.wrong {
  background-color: white;
}
.right:hover {
   background-color: yellow;
}.wrong:hover {
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

Using Jquery I change the background colors of classes wrong and right to green and red and after 1.5 seconds I return them back to normal with the **following code:**

```
//change colors
     $('.right').click( function() {
        var $el = $(".wrong"),
        originalColor = $el.css("background-color");
        var $el2 = $(".wrong:hover"),
        hover = $el2.css("background-color:hover");
        $('.wrong').css("background-color" , "red");
        $('.right').css("background-color" , "green");
        test(originalColor,hover);
        })


     async function test(originalColor,hover){
       await sleep(1500);
        $('.wrong').css("background-color" , originalColor);
        $('.right').css("background-color" , originalColor);
        $('.wrong:hover').css("background-color" , hover);
        $('.right:hover').css("background-color" , hover);
     }
    function sleep(ms){
      return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }
//change colors
```

Everything works fine except the hover part.After the first Jquery click function the `background-color` of the hover is lost.It looks like that `$el2 = $(".wrong:hover")` is syntactically wrong.Can you help my on how to chage the code so I do not lose the `background-color: yellow;` on the hover after the first Jquery function??
**Fiddle example:**
[Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/zekes/960oLana/7/)

Comment: Duplicate, please see a similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275891/jquery-hover-and-class-selector

Comment: @Levano I don't see any similarities with the link you posted.. I don't want to change my hover dynamicly I just want it just to remain as it is..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add/Remove class instead of css

```js
 $('.right,.wrong').click( function() {
        var $el = $(".wrong"),
        originalColor = $el.css("background-color");
        var $el2 = $(".wrong:hover"),
        hover = $el2.css("background-color:hover");
        $('.wrong').addClass("red");
        $('.right').addClass("green");
        test(originalColor,hover);
        })


     async function test(originalColor,hover){
       await sleep(1500);
        $('.wrong').removeClass("red");
        $('.right').removeClass("green");
     }
    function sleep(ms){
      return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }
```

```css
div{
  width:50%;
  height:40px;
  float:left;
}
.right{
  background-color: white;
}
.wrong {
  background-color: white;
}
.right:hover {
   background-color: yellow;
}.wrong:hover {
   background-color: yellow;
}
.red,.red:hover{
  background-color: red;
}
.green,.green:hover{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="right">Right</div>
<div class="wrong">Wrong</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know and experienced it (experience is the best teacher), **:psuedo elements are not part of the DOM. So, Javascript selectors can not select or manuplate them.**

You might try adding classes for hover state then you can check or do whatever you want with that class; for example ".hover"